# Add space to root partition - couldn't use Gparted

Tags: partitioning, disk-management

I tried using Gparted utility to allocate more space to the root partition, but could not get that done.

Can you please suggest steps on how to change partitioning to allow more space on root partition?

[image: Gparted screenshot showing large NTFS partition and many very small ext4 partitions]

Comment: You will have a huge task, because whole ubuntu partitions you have are in an extended one (/dev/sda3). In addition to having to resize your Windows partition (/dev/sda2) to save space, you will have to resize sda3, too. To make matters worse, sda3 has only 29Gb. Too smaller for Ubuntu install. It would be better to reinstall everything again (including Windows) or installing Ubuntu in a newer HD.

Comment: I wonder what are the other four ext4 partitions? Are they needed? It's not possible to do much with the current layout. I am afraid you'd need to reinstall Ubuntu. There is no need to reinstall Windows.

Comment: You can do this, but it takes several steps. You have to move the partitions so that the unallocated space is adjacent to your root partition. move sda4 -> apply changes -> make sda3 larger to include unallocated space -> apply changes move all the other partitions in sda3, one a a time, until unallocated space is adjacent to your root partition. Finally resize root partition.

Comment: As there have been a lot of questions like this one and writing a general answer is difficult, I just made a video about it: https://youtu.be/l0n5WSr9e5I I think showing people how to change the partitions is a better approach than text, by way of exception.